# Elixir Ecto, failed change type to jsonb

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have an error while modifying column type to jsonb or map. Here is my migration file:

```
  def change do
    alter table(:disbursements) do
      modify :reason, :map
    end
  end
```

and I receive error like below:

```
** (Postgrex.Error) ERROR 42804 (datatype_mismatch) column "reason" cannot be cast automatically to type jsonb

hint: You might need to specify "USING reason::jsonb".
(ecto_sql) lib/ecto/adapters/sql.ex:624: Ecto.Adapters.SQL.raise_sql_call_error/1
```

My question is how can I add extra command `USING reason::jsonb` to my migration file ?

Comment: Run raw SQL instead.

Comment: yes i can, but how about if my code will be run by my team ? should i tell one by one to run raw sql ?

Comment: oh got it, you mean run like this one ? https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/f5a0cafa7e-execute-raw-sql-in-an-ecto-migration

Comment: Yes, like this one.